# getting datafrom two tables collectively and get all the rows from table A

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

I have two tables from where i want the rows to come collectively.
table a is like this

```
id a_name image      category
1  name1  image1.png  cate1
2  name2  image2.png  cate2
3  name3  image3.png  cate3
4  name4  image4.png  cate3
5  name5  image5.png  cate1
6  name6  image6.png  cate2
7  name7  image7.png  cate3
8  name8  image8.png  cate1
```

and a table b like this (a_id is the id of any of the above table's row)

```
id user_id  a_id email amount   code  active
1   123       2    s@s    23      23ke  1
2   542       1    s@s    23      23ke  1
3   523       2    s@s    23      23ke  1
4   423       6    s@s    23      23ke  1
5   103       5    s@s    23      23ke  1
6   523       5    s@s    23      23ke  0
```

i want to join two tables in such a way that whenever i run the query it should return all the rows of table A joined with table B. i have used join but it gets only the rows where join is successfully applied. the rows to be fetched from table b should be in terms of user_id also.
for example:
 if iam searching for the data of user with user_id =523. then it should output following. (id field is from table a)

```
 id  a_name image      user_id email amount  code active
 1  name1  image1.png    -       -     -      -      -
 2  name2  image2.png    523    s@s    s@s    23KE   1
 3  name3  image3.png     -      -     -       -     -
 4  name4  image4.png     -      -     -       -     -
 5  name5  image5.png    523     s@s   23     23KE   0
 6  name6  image6.png     -       -    -       -     -
 7  name7  image7.png     -       -    -       -     -
 8  name8  image8.png     -       -    -       -     -
```

I am using mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Outer Join,

```
SELECT * from a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id AND b.user_id = 523
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want a `left join`

```
select a.*, b.*
from a left join
     b
     on a.id = b.a_id and b.user_id = 523;
```